# Google Custom Detail marker iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps-markers, gmsmapview

I wanna create the custom detail marker like shown in the image below. But the issue is how to handle the size of the detail view and its postion.

[image]

Comment: As per my exprience you can create custom callout on marker but not marker it self customized based on your requirement.

Comment: I've been suffering with Infowindo customization in GoogleMapsSdk For iOS from a lot of days like you!

This might help you - https://github.com/nareshreddym/Custom-Info-Window-Google-maps-iOS

Or This - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599791/custom-info-window-in-ios-google-maps-sdk/36009430#36009430

Happy coading :)